# Parsing a JSON file with multiple levels in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've some trouble with parsing a JSON file into a MySQL database. It's an export of some Facebookstats.

Because I've multiple export of multiple pages, it's important that I've the corresponding ID in the database.

The JSONfile (or cURL from Facebook) looks like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "name": "impressions",
        "period": "week",
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 123456789,
                "end_time": "2016-01-01T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
                "value": 12345678,
                "end_time": "2016-01-02T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
                "value": 1234567,
                "end_time": "2016-01-03T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
                "value": 123456,
                "end_time": "2016-01-04T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
                "value": 12345,
                "end_time": "2016-01-05T08:00:00+0000"
            }
        ],
        "title": "Weekly Impressions",
        "description": "The number of impressions seen of any content associated with your Page. (Total Count)",
        "id": "101010101010\/insights\/page_impressions\/week"
    }
],
"paging": {
    "previous": "1",
    "next": "2"
    }
}
```

I would, ideally, parse this data into a MySQL database that looks like this:

```
id                      value               end_time
101010101010            123456789           2016-01-01T08:00:00+0000
101010101010            12345678            2016-01-02T08:00:00+0000
101010101010            1234567             2016-01-03T08:00:00+0000
101010101010            123456              2016-01-04T08:00:00+0000
101010101010            12345               2016-01-05T08:00:00+0000
```

I hope someone had some ideas :-)

Comment: What have you tried? PHP can decode the JSON to an array easily. A few nested foreach would easily get the data so you could do the inserts into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_decode()`. Example:

```
$jsonString = '{
"data": [
{
    "name": "impressions",
    "period": "week",
    "values": [
        {
            "value": 123456789,
            "end_time": "2016-01-01T08:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
            "value": 12345678,
            "end_time": "2016-01-02T08:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
            "value": 1234567,
            "end_time": "2016-01-03T08:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
            "value": 123456,
            "end_time": "2016-01-04T08:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
            "value": 12345,
            "end_time": "2016-01-05T08:00:00+0000"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Weekly Impressions",
    "description": "The number of impressions seen of any content associated with your Page. (Total Count)",
    "id": "101010101010\/insights\/page_impressions\/week"
}
],
"paging": {
    "previous": "1",
    "next": "2"
    }
}';
```

Then decode it to an associative array:

```
 $assocData = json_decode($jsonString, true); //Setting second optional parameter to true makes it return an associative array.
```

Then access it however you want:

```
$data = $assocData['data'];
```